# Syntax error in Python control block

Tags: python, syntax

I am new to programming. I am making a six sided dice (fair). Here is my code:

```
import random

def dice(rolls):
    results=[]
    for i in range(rolls):
        random.random()=n
        if n<= .17:
            results.append('1')
        elif n<= .33:
            results.append('2')
        elif n<= .5:
            results.append('3')
        elif n<= .67:
            results.append('4')
        elif n<= .83:
           results,append('5')
        else n<= 1:
            results.append('6')
    return results
```

Basically I am attempting to generate a random number between 0 and 1. If it falls in between these categories I want it to return that number in an appending list. I get an error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" IDLE then highlights 'n' from "else n<=1:" What's going on?
Thank You!

Comment: `else` doesn't take a conditional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
else n<= 1:
```

needs to either be:

```
elif n<= 1:
```

or just:

```
else:
```

else takes no condition, and is the 'catch-all' if no other conditions were met

Comment: Further to this `random.random()=n` should become `n=random.random()`.

Comment: Thank You! I had a few other errors in the code shown above, but I figured them out. Ok yeah that makes sense..since there is nothing else left it makes sense that just "else" would be needed for the last condition. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Here is more pythonic version:

```
import random

def dice(rolls):
    return [random.randrange(6)+1 for i in range(rolls)]
```

or even

```
import random

dice = lambda rolls: [random.randrange(6)+1 for i in range(rolls)]
```

random has function for such cases which returns int value in specified range -> `randrange(..)`, so there is no need in such heavy logic for defining dice.

Comment: `randrange(6)` will return 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5. You need to use `randint(1, 6)` or `randrange(1, 7)` to produce the correct behavior

Comment: oh..yeah you're right haha. That would be much easier. Anyways my code fails when you set a given variable lower than the one preceding it. Thank you everyone

Comment: @dnic2693 sorry, didn't understand `my code fails when you set a given variable lower than the one preceding it`